# Why is Facebook telling me "Only add people who you know"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-privacy, facebook-friend-request

This is the message I am receiving:

> Only add people who you know
>   Please only send friend requests to people who you know personally.
>   If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know

Why am I receiving this message?

Comment: Are you adding a bunch of friends one after the other?

Comment: Not really but I have been sending many people friend requests...

Comment: You are true to some extent..

Comment: That's probably it. It's an anti-spam measure.

Comment: Yes but now should I do..

Comment: There must be some way to write to get rid of this...Btw their chat is not responsive..

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is working to improve their security and algorithms which includes cleaning up current "fake" or "hack" accounts by "people you don't know" and encouraging people not to accept friend requests from these accounts.

**I think** this is part of a larger marketing campaign for FB to regain security and trust after it was found out that FB was somehow used by a 3rd party to sway elections. I'm not familiar with what happened in any detail though.  Here's a recent NPR article about the scandal: https://www.npr.org/2018/04/11/601323233/6-facts-we-know-about-fake-news-in-the-2016-election

Comment: What can I do to get rid of this?'